# Use Assetic with BootstrapBundle

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assetic

I am trying to use the [BoostrapBundle](http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com) for Symfony2, but I get stuck.

I tried to install the assets and use assetic using [the tutorial](http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/getting-started#download-assets), but I don't know how to use it on a twig file.

I tried with:

```
{% javascripts '@BcBootstrapBundle' %}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ bootstrap_js }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

But I get the error:

> An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template
>   ("There is no "BcBootstrapBundle" asset.")

According to the manual:

> When you have AsseticBundle installed BootstrapBundle will
>   automatically configure the assets from Twitter Bootstrap for you. If
>   you want to change the configuration you can do this by overwritting
>   the Assetic configuration.

But there's nothing about the good syntax to use on a twig file, even in the [BootstrapDemoBundle](https://github.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-demo-bundle/blob/develop/Resources/views/layout.html.twig) (if you look at the source code, you'll see a `use Assetic` comment, but it doesn't help).

In the [next section](http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/getting-started#html-template), they give an usage example which is supposed to use bootstrap, but it looks like there is something missing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

They use a simple `{{ asset('file') }}`, who points `web/` directory (but I never put any file there, and so didn't `assets:install`).

So my question is:

> How to use the preconfigured assets to create a bootstrapped view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dump the assets first using [assetic:dump](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#cookbook-assetic-dumping). This command will generate the files you need and then you can include them with the `asset(...)` function.

Comment: So simple, but just didn't knew about it. Thank you!!